# How to wait in Angular for two calls to finish

Tags: angular, typescript, subscribe

I have this function that I want to run. The problem is that it doesn't wait for the two calls to finish and instantiate `rule1` and `rule2` so I get error that `rule1.optionhead is undefined`. I have tried to have the code nested to each `subscribe` but then the create execution happens more times than I want. What can I do to fix it?

To clarify,
I use this for loop because the `selectedScenario` is an array of IDs which are in an input form `ngValue`

```
saveFunction() {

  for (const pair of this.selectedScenario) {
    this.ruleToSave = null;

    this.ruleService.find(pair[0]).subscribe((ruleResponse: HttpResponse < Rule > ) => {
      this.rule1 = ruleResponse.body;

    });

    this.ruleService.find(pair[1]).subscribe((ruleResponse: HttpResponse < Rule > ) => {
      this.rule2 = ruleResponse.body;

    });

    const head1 = this.rule1.optionHead;
    const head2 = this.rule2.optionHead;

    if (
      this.selectedOption === head1 &&
      this.selectedOption !== head2 &&
      (this.selectedWeakerOption === '' || head2 === this.selectedWeakerOption)
    ) {
      ..some code
      this.subscribeToSaveResponse(this.ruleService.createRule(this.ruleToSave));
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: You aren't actually waiting for *either*, let alone both. I'd recommend reading up on RxJS, and async in general.

Comment: You can use one of the rxjs operator `combineLatest` or `forkJoin`

Comment: @BoradAkash So, you propose to use forkJoin and in the subscribe i will paste all the other code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ForkJoin

```
  Observable.forkJoin([
                this.ruleService.find(pair[0]),
                this.ruleService.find(pair[1])])
                .subscribe(
    (result: any[]) =>{ 
           this.rule1 = result[0]; 
           this.rule1 = result[1]; 

        ..Your code

    }
    );
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use this code for that

```
removeAll() {
  Promise.all([
    this.storage.remove(key1),
    this.storage.remove(key2),
    this.storage.remove(key3),
  ]).then(value => doSomething());
```

Comment: If you are going to post and answer, you should make it relevant to the OP. What you have posted here doesn't seem to have anything to do with what was asked above. Nor does it have any explanation of what you are solving with this code.